# Процедура SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть процедура:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sqn
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 13;

CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1
(
first_name IN VARCHAR2 ,
last_name IN VARCHAR2 ,
email IN VARCHAR2 ,
phone_number IN VARCHAR2 ,
birthday IN DATE ,
job_name IN VARCHAR2 ,
department_name IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
s_first_name varchar2(20);
s_last_name varchar2(20);
s_job_name varchar2(40);
s_department_name varchar2(40);
j_exists number;
d_exists number;
s_job_id number;
s_department_id number;
email_err EXCEPTION;
phone_err EXCEPTION;
age_err EXCEPTION;
job_err EXCEPTION;
department_err EXCEPTION;
BEGIN 
--Проверка имени
s_first_name := INITCAP(first_name);

--Проверка фамилии
s_last_name := INITCAP(last_name); 

--Проверка email
IF (not REGEXP_LIKE (email, '^\w+@\w+(\.\w{2,4}){1,2}[$]')) THEN RAISE email_err;
END IF;

--Проверка номера 
IF (not REGEXP_LIKE (phone_number, '\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$')) THEN RAISE phone_err;
END IF;

--Проверка возраста 
IF (to_date(birthday,'dd.mm.yyyy') - to_date(SYSDATE,'dd.mm.yyyy')) < 6570 THEN RAISE age_err;
END IF;

--Проверка названия должности
DECLARE 
j_exists NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT job_id 
INTO j_exists
FROM jobs
WHERE job_name = s_job_name ;
END;

IF j_exists = 0 THEN RAISE job_err; 
ELSE s_job_id:=j_exists;
END IF; 


--Проверка названия отдела
DECLARE 
d_exists NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT department_id 
INTO d_exists
FROM departments
WHERE department_name = s_department_name ;
END;

IF d_exists = 0 THEN RAISE department_err; 
ELSE s_department_id:=d_exists;
END IF; 

--Вставка новой записи 
INSERT into staff values (sqn.NEXTVAL, s_first_name, s_last_name, email, phone_number, SYSDATE, birthday, null, s_job_id, s_department_id);

EXCEPTION
WHEN email_err THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20040, 'Неправильный email');
WHEN phone_err THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20041, 'Неправильный телефонный номер'); 
WHEN age_err THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20042, 'Возраст меньше 18 лет');
WHEN job_err THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20043, 'Неверное название должности');
WHEN department_err THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20044, 'Неверное название отдела');
END PROCEDURE1;

begin
PROCEDURE1('иван','таранов', 'ghghfh', '(991)-435-65-54', 25-MAY-82, 'Программист','Отдел развития');
END;
```

Вроде все правильно, но выскакивает ошибка:

```
Error(86,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"
```

Не могу понять как исправить, база данных Oracle

Comment: Шаг номер 1 - нормально отформатировать код.

Comment: Шаг номер 2 - отметить в коде на какой строке возникает ошибка.

Comment: Он же написал - в 86-й строке. Нам осталось только посчитать строки.

Comment: `begin
PROCEDURE1(...);
END;` на этом begin ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так (скорее всего):

```
...
END PROCEDURE1;
/  -- сюда надо слэш вставить

begin
PROCEDURE1('иван','таранов', 'ghghfh', '(991)-435-65-54', 25-MAY-82, 'Программист','Отдел развития');
END;
```